# How can I get rid of vertical spacing of empty rows in a QGridLayout in Qt?

Tags: qt, layout, dynamic, dialog, resize

So I have a dialog that consists of one `QGridLayout` that has two columns of widgets (labels and comboboxes). Depending on the selections of the comboboxes some rows might be hidden.

I figured out that having the dialog call `self.layout().setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SetFixedSize)` as it shows/hides the comboboxes would make the dialog change size accordingly.

But then I realized that the layout was still showing the vertical spacing of empty rows, thus making the dialog show too much space here and there.

How can I get rid of this? Is there a way to have the layout resize to show only vertical spacing of rows that have visible widgets?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution. Using `QVBoxLayout` instead of `QGridLayout` somehow makes widgets **and** their vertical spacing go away when a widget is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use `QLayout::takeAt ( int index )` to take out the item, once the visibility is set to `false` & use `QLayout::addItem ( QLayoutItem * item )` when you need it back in your layout.

Keep in mind that if an item is removed, other items will be renumbered. So you have to plan what you do accordingly. Refer the [documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qlayout.html#takeAt) .